# cost, time and tools had Google reverse-engineered Java packages?

Tags: disassembly, android, java, api, dalvik

In the context of [Oracle vs. Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.):

> This is not a case where Google reverse-engineered Oracle’s Java
>   packages to gain access to unprotected functional elements contained
>   therein.

page 48 ORACLE AMERICA , INC . v. GOOGLE INC .

My question is, **had** Google, or, were to Google **to** reverse engineer Oracle's Java packages:

What tools would Google have used?
How long would it have taken, approximately?
What would've been the estimated cost?

1. *(I'm not asking whether or not an API should or can be copyrighted, or the merits of what Google did.)*
2. *(To clarify:  Google **didn't** reverse engineer "Java"; at least one comment defines what they did as [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).)*

Comment: As far as I know, the source code of Java is freely available.

Comment: @joxeankoret yes, it is..but there's a licensing agreement.  So, I really, really, don't want to troll, that's not the intent.  It's a very narrow **technical** question.  I can put the question in context of appeals court decision, but that's wayyy off topic..

Comment: Reading publicly available source code doesn't count as reverse engineering. So there was no reason for them to reverse engineer anything. Now, IF they had had only the .class files, they would have had to use a java decompiler, possibly fix decompiler errors, annotate the sources, do some optimizations, whatever. But there's no serious way to guesstimate timeframe and cost - running something like `jd-gui` over the java classes cost an hour. Cleaning the source code and assigning meaningful comments costs months.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm the reason to reverse engineer is because OpenJDK is under the GPL; Google uses the ASL, instead.

Comment: License issues can be a reason to *re-engineer* something (build a new software from scratch that behaves like the original, but doesn't share code with the original). This something different from *reverse-enigneer*ing, (investigate an implementation to find out how it works). Google [re-engineered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reengineering) Java, but they didnt - and didn't have to - [reverse-enigneer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) Java.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I think it's a contentious claim that Google refactored Java, as that link leads to, but be that as it may.  I'm not asking about license issues, I'm only asking about the [practicalities involved](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303/).

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, they didn't reverse engineer anything. They wrote an independent implementation based on reading the documentation of the APIs. Oracle's contention was that simply having the same method names in the APIs was a copyright violation, which is obviously silly.

Comment: Agreed, they didn't reverse engineer.  The question is hypothetical:  "what if?"  What I'm asking is, and I think Guntram gave most of the answer, is that they would've/could've done the reverse engineering with `jd-gui`, and, based on his estimate, it would've meant months of delay.

Comment: Why would do you anything with jd-gui? At least use a real decompiler like procyon.

Comment: sure, I just asking, in general, what tools would be involved and, just to estimate, the cost and time involved to actually reverse engineer on this scale.